# Tabbed application troubles in xcode

Tags: xcode

I am working with my first tabbed application in xcode. I am just testing with some stuff since I'm relatively new to programming. I am just using the 2 views already put into the template. I am putting a slider into the first view and am going to attach it to a text box with numbers. But that isn't the problem! This is probably really stupid and simple, but when i run the application just to see the stuff on the simulator, it is just showing a black screen. NO CLUE WHY! But its killing me and would love some help!

Comment: Yeah, what are you using? Storyboards, .xib, through code?

Comment: I am using the latest version of xcode. 4.5.2. I have declared the properties of the UISlider and the UITextField in my FirstViewController.m file. And I have control clicked them and connected them with the objects in the storyboards. I'm just not sure why when i run the application that I can't at least see the screen?

Comment: When i run the program. It goes into the debugging area and pops up saying return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class])); @AceLegend

Comment: And the issue is that it says Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

Comment: You are not suppose to make connections in AppDelegate. You should use a ViewController for each class. I.E. FirstViewController, SecondViewController. AppDelegate is usually only used for calling save/restore messages.

Comment: In my main.m that is where is says return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class])); Do i delete this? Sorry i'm just new to objective-c and the whole programming deal..

Comment: In my main.m that is where is says return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class])); Do i delete this? Sorry i'm just new to objective-c and the whole programming deal.. @AceLegend

Comment: I think it might be easier to start a new project. This time note that when you want to declare something, you need to make sure you are connecting to the right class. You can tell what class from the IB. I'll attach a picture to my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not suppose to make connections in AppDelegate. You should use a ViewController for each class. I.E. FirstViewController, SecondViewController. AppDelegate is usually only used for calling save/restore messages.

You are getting the error because the storyboard view is assuming you are assigning it to the correct view. When you create the storyboard say you named it TestApp. Then, you should have a few classes. TestAppDelegate, TestAppDelegateFirstViewController, TestAppDelegateSecondViewController. Or something along those lines. FirstViewController should connect to the first view on the tab view. The Second should attach to the second.

AppDelegate is almost never used for UI. I would suggest you find a book on the matter. I'll suggest "iOS Programming. The Big Nerd Ranch Guide". It helped me a lot when I started.

Photo Exmaple:

[image: Example of Custom Class]

Comment: Thank you! This pic helped me alot! Sorry I'm still getting used to the basic stuff! and thank you again for the book suggestion, i plan on getting it soon @AceLegend

Comment: No problem. Good luck to you and your endeavors.

Answer (score 0):

I did end up starting a new project. Weird that the black screen showed up.. not really sure why that error was popping up.. I'm not really that knowledgable about the different errors and bugs that a program can have yet! Getting closer though!